# Why "Documents & Data" is consuming so much space in iPhone?

Tags: storage, icloud

Looking at the **iTunes** storage information associated to my iPhone 5S, it seems that Documents & Data occupies around **3.5 GB** of space.

[image]

On the other hand, on the iPhone, Documents & Data stored on **iCloud** are around **300 MB** (so much less).

[image]

Which value should I trust? Moreover, if iCloud just requires 300 MB to store documents and data, what is the meaning of the 3.5 GB data that appears on iTunes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is normal. You can refer to this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201656

**If storage amounts on an iOS device differ from what you see reported in iTunes**

> Since iTunes categorizes cached files as Other, reported usage for
>   Music or Videos might differ. To view usage on your iOS device, go to
>   Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage.